# How to delete record from dbf file using python dbf module?

Tags: python, visual-foxpro, dbf

I'm trying to write/delete records in a visual foxpro 6 dbf file, using python 2.7 and the dbf package:

```
import dbf
tbl = dbf.Table('test.dbf')
tbl.open()
rec = tbl[0]
print(rec.__class__)
rec.delete_record()
```

Result:

```
<class 'dbf.ver_2.Record'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Projects/test/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    rec.delete_record()
  File "C:\Python\Projects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\dbf\ver_2.py", line 2503, in __getattr__
    raise FieldMissingError(name)
dbf.ver_2.FieldMissingError: 'delete_record:  no such field in table'
```

Here is the documentation for that package: http://pythonhosted.org/dbf/

The record object really does not have this method, but it is documented. The table is opened in read-write mode. (But it is also true that the Table() constructor should return an opened table, but it returns a closed table instead.)

What am I doing wrong?

The biggest problem is that there are no other options. The only other package I know of is "dbfpy" but that does not handle vfoxpro 6 tables, and it does not handle different character encodings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That documentation is out of date.  (My apologies.)

What you want is:

```
dbf.delete(rec)
tbl.pack()
```

Comment: Okay, and what about record.write_record() - do I need to write out changes somehow?

Comment: @nagylzs:  Changes are written as you go.  So if you don't want to save things one field at a time you have to store them up.  Feel free to ask that as a question so I can write a better answer than this comment.  :)

Comment: Asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839421/how-to-modify-and-save-records-in-a-dbf-file-using-python-dbf-module

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use **dbfpy** module which allows you to access records public variable **deleted**. Example code:

```
from dbfpy import dbf
...
dbfFile = dbf.Dbf("DbfFileName", readOnly=True)
for rec in dbfFile:
  if rec.deleted:
    #action if deleted
dbfFile.close()
```