# How to modify and save records in a dbf file using python dbf module?

Tags: python, visual-foxpro, dbf

Here is the documentation for that package: http://pythonhosted.org/dbf/

The record object does not have a write_record() method, but it is documented.

Do I need to call something to commit changes to the file before closing the table?

This question is related to: [How to delete record from dbf file using python dbf module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832107/how-to-delete-record-from-dbf-file-using-python-dbf-module)

Comment: My apologies for having you create this question.  When I went looking for one of my previous answers I found one that exactly fit.